# Packages name conflicting with getters and setters?

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-construction, package

folks. So, I've came across this compilation error a while ago.. As there's an easy fix and I didn't find anything relevant at the time, I eventually let it go.

I just remembered it and I'm now wondering if this is really part of the language grammar (which I highly doubt) or if it's a compiler bug. I'm being purely curious about this -- it doesn't really affect development, but it would be nice to see if any of you have seen this already.

```
package view {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        private var _view:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public function Main() {
            this.test();
        }

        private function test():void {
            trace(this.view.x, this.view.y);
            //1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property x through a reference with static type view:Main.
            //1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property y through a reference with static type view:Main.
            //Note that I got this due to the package name.
            //It runs just fine if I rename the package or getter.
        }

        public function get view():Sprite {
            return this._view;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say this is either a compiler bug or an inconsistency in the [spec](http://livedocs.adobe.com/specs/actionscript/3/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=as3_specification.html).

Quote from the chapter 11.1 Package namespace (I'd link directly, but the docs use frames):

> Packages exist only at compile time.
>   The static existence of packages
>   allows us to give them certain
>   properties that would not be possible
>   if they could be manipulated at
>   runtime. In particular:
>
> Package names may have embedded dots.
>   Fully qualified package references may
>   and must be expressed using the dot
>   operator rather than the usual ::
>   syntax for qualified names.
>
> But because there is no runtime value
>   for a package name, packages cannot be
>   aliased or otherwise used in an
>   expression that uses a runtime value.
>
> When encountered in a valid context by
>   the compiler, the meaning of a package
>   name becomes fixed; any interpretation
>   at runtime is no longer possible.
>
> For this reason, a package name always
>   shadows locally defined names,
>   independent of the scope chain, when
>   that package name is used on the left
>   hand side of a dot operator.

Now, from the above, I gather that this line:

```
trace(this.view.x, this.view.y);
```

Shouldn't be interpreted by the compiler as refering to the `view` package, since it seems to contradict this point -- I'll call it A):

> packages cannot be aliased or otherwise 
>   used in an expression that uses a runtime 
>   value

Because `this`, unless I'm mistaken, is a runtime value.

Then, if you use `this` the ambiguity could be solved as your getter, I think, but according to this paragraph -- let's call it B), it won't:

> For this reason, a package name always 
>   shadows locally defined names, 
>   independent of the scope chain, 
>   when that package name is used on the 
>   left hand side of a dot operator.

So, if you don't use `this`, it's clear from the spec that `view.x` should be interpreted as a reference to the defintion of `x` in the `view` package.

If you explicitly say `this`, there's a contradiction between A) and B), as I see it. According to A) there should be no aliasing; but the aliasing is happening, it seems, because there's a package name used on the left of a dot operator. So my guess is the compiler is not parsing the package in context, so to speak, just checking if any name on the left of a dot operator matches the name of a defined package.

Comment: +1. In AS3, my rule of thumb is: avoid naming conflicts between global identifiers (packages & classes) with scoped identifiers (variables & properties) at all cost, because even if the context is really clear, the compiler might choke.

Comment: I guess I should be filling a JIRA report, lol. By the way, I noticed doing `this.view`doesn't generate any errors. :P